# Elasticsearch on mac with brew doesn't let me run nor uninstall

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I installed Elasticsearch with brew but I can't start kibana because I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot delete files/folders outside the current working directory. Can be overriden with the `force` option.
```

The `force`option doesn't work either.

I could not find any solution to solve it

Now I want to uninstall Elastic, but when I try `brew unistall elasticsearch` I get:

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "elasticsearch". Did you mean elasticsearch@6?
```

No clue what `elasticsearch@6` supposed to be and it doesn't exist.
How can I either get Kibana running, or get rid of Elastic?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following commands

```
brew uninstall elasticsearch
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch
rm -rf /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch
```

Comment: Thats what I tried. I get this: `Error: No available formula or cask with the name "elasticsearch". Did you mean elasticsearch@6?`

Comment: which version did you install?
Try with the specific version name like : elasticsearch:7.14.1

Comment: 7.15.0 i tried it but i get the same error